# Why am I getting a "Permission Denied" error when posting data into Firebase realtime database with Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase

I am developing a bookshop app with Angular 9.0 and Firebase Realtime Database. So far I had managed to write and read with the default rules.

```
{
  "rules":{
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
  }
}
```

However, I have already started with authentication. I can now create, update and delete users. As regards with updating the user info, I would like that any user can store his/her personal details (only visible to the user). From what I have read, the rules for "users" should be like this:

```
{
  "rules":{
    "users":{
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to implement this now in my post requests. I have set a service for that:

```
// USERDETAILS.SERVICE.TS 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {UserDetails} from '../user/userDetails.model'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserDetailsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  submitUserDetails(details: UserDetails, userId) {
    this.http
      .post(
        'https://proyectoangular-5f739.firebaseio.com/users/' + userId +'/details.json',
        details
      )
      .subscribe((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
      });
  }
}
```

The service is called from the component, which is no more than a form where I get all the data
with @ViewChild and annex the id that I have stored in the browser (not sure if this is the uid that Firebase is requesting).

```
// USER-DETAILS.COMPONENT.TS
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetailsService } from 'src/app/services/userDetails.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserDetails } from 'src/app/user/userDetails.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('userForm', {static: true}) userForm: NgForm

  constructor(private userDetailsService : UserDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    const userDetails = this.userForm.value;
    const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    console.log(userId)
    this.userDetailsService.submitUserDetails(userDetails, userId.id)
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After looking for Angular projects in Github, I found the way to do it. I have already tested with the rules shown above and it works flawlessly. The problem was with the auth_token, which had to be included in the post request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {UserDetails} from '../user/userDetails.model'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserDetailsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  submitUserDetails(details: UserDetails, userId, token) {
    this.http
      .post(
        'https://proyectoangular-5f739.firebaseio.com/users/' + userId +'/details.json?auth=' +token,
        details
      )
      .subscribe((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
      });
  }
}
```

In the component.ts ->

```
// USER-DETAILS.COMPONENT.TS

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetailsService } from 'src/app/services/userDetails.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserDetails } from 'src/app/user/userDetails.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.css']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('userForm', {static: true}) userForm: NgForm

  constructor(private userDetailsService : UserDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    const userDetails = this.userForm.value;
    const userId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    console.log(userId._token)
    this.userDetailsService.submitUserDetails(userDetails, userId.id, userId._token)
  }
}
```